# Need a theme that let the posted content stretched maximum width

Tags: themes, css, theme-recommendation

(Please note I'm NOT asking about `wordpress.org` but about `wordpress.com`)

I just posted a new entry but my current theme has a fixed width which makes my post become *buggy* and surely myself and the readers won't like it very much!

So, I'm looking for another theme that has the content width maximized. If you know ones, please share! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.com had recently got much improved catalog of themes with search, filtering and other nifties.

See [all themes with flexible width template](http://theme.wordpress.com/themes/widths/flexible-width/).

If nothing fits there is [paid option](http://en.wordpress.com/products/) to allow CSS customization.